# clearcontents range of cells

Tags: excel, vba

I'm new to VBA and trying to run a very simple subroutine, but am getting an error. I want to clear a range of cells from K7 to an indefinite number of rows and column V. Here is the code:

```
Sub UpdateMatrix()

    Worksheets("Prioritization Matrix").Range("K7", Cells(Row.Count, 22)).ClearContents

End Sub
```

Here is the error:

```
vba runtime error 424 object required
```

All the examples I've seen lead me to believe that this code should work, but it doesn't. Suggestions?

Thanks!

Comment: Where are you getting `Row` from? That is the issue

Comment: You probably need `Rows.Count`. Additionally, the second parameter of `Cells` can be a column letter in quotes, e.g. `"V"`. That makes it more readable.

Answer (score 0):

- First, if you're running your code from another sheet than the Prioritization Matrix, you're creating a 3d range, which fails, you need to make your reference to Cells absolute, not relative.
- Second, the `Count` applies to `Rows`, not `Row`.

  ```
  Worksheets("Prioritization Matrix").Range("K7", Worksheets("Prioritization Matrix").Cells(Worksheets("Prioritization Matrix").Rows.Count, 22)).ClearContents
  ```
- Finally, you're clearing a very wide range, you can restrict the clearing by using `Used Range`:

  ```
  Sub UpdateMatrix()
  Dim sht As Worksheet

  Set sht = Worksheets("Prioritization Matrix")

  Intersect(sht.Range("K7", sht.Cells(Rows.Count, 22)), sht.UsedRange).ClearContents

  End Sub
  ```